# How to set a local variable to the result of sql query in a batch file?

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, batch-file

Is there any way to retreive the result set of a sql query in a local variable; the query is to be run in a batch file. What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
set varname = osql -S%dstserver% -d%dstDB% -Q"SELECT name from table_name where Id = %siteId%" %osqluser% -b
```

varname is my local variable.

I am quite new in sql so any help would be greatly appreciated1

Answer (score 2):

Write the result to the file and then read the file. In your case you need to read the first line (and possibly `trim` it).

Add following parameters to your query:

```
osql -S%dstserver% -d%dstDB% -Q"SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT name from table_name where Id = %siteId%" %osqluser% -b -w 9999 -h-1 -o tempres.txt
```

- -o ...: output file (which you need to read later)
- -h-1: disable header
- -w 9999: to ensure that it handles correctly cases when your `name` is longer then default 80 characters
- `SET NOCOUNT ON;` before real query to disable the status string like `(1 row affected)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `for /f` to iterate over the output of a command:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (`your command`) do ...
```

You don't need a temporary file at all; it doesn't gain you anything here (except having to think about where you may have write permissions and remember to delete the file afterwards).

`for` iterates line-wise over the output, tokenizing as it goes. That's why there is a `delims=` at the end which effectively disables any tokenizing so you don't get your output split at spaces. There are other options, such as `skip=n` which will skip *n* lines before starting processing which you can use to ignore a header or so.

Inside that loop you can then do the following:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (`your command`) do set VAR=%%x
```

Be very careful what you do afterwards with that variable, though, as it may contain characters the shell treats as special, such as `>`, `<`, `&`, etc. You may create yourself here some sort of Batch Injection vulnerability when doing something like the following:

```
echo %VAR%
```

and someone decides to put the following string in his name:

```
foo & rd /s q \
```

If you know that only a single line with usable content returns and the rest is useless junk then you can break the loop prematurely:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in (`your command`) do set VAR=%%x&goto break
:break
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `set /p`:

```
osql -S%dstserver% -d%dstDB% -Q"SET NOCOUNT ON;SELECT name from table_name where Id = %siteId%" %osqluser% -b -w 9999 -h-1 -o tempres.txt  

set /p varname=<tempres.txt
```

(Borrowing `osql` parameters from [van's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2324780/how-to-set-a-local-variable-to-the-result-of-sql-query-in-a-batch-file/2325457#2325457) answer)

Comment: +1: nice, although reads only one row, but this is enough for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the result to a file containing `set` statements.

```
@echo off
osql -E -S servername -h-1 -Q "set nocount on; select 'set var=42'" > c:\set.bat
call c:\set.bat
echo %VAR%
```

This results in `42` being written to the screen.  To select a name from a table, use a SQL statement like:

```
select 'set var=' + name from table_name where Id = %siteId%
```